Aiogram Telegram Bot Python
I have a problem. In previous versions of aiogram (2.0, 2.5) Dispatcher had a method "process_message".
As I remember, It had a meaning of continuing message to another handler.
How is it called now?
Thanks in advance for help

Look to middleware to preprocess the update before it get the handler
You can bind the middleware to a separate router if you want it to work only when you need it
